# golang decimal to hex conversion error

Tags: go, printf, hex, decimal

Problem with precision

The setup is a physical i-button (1-wire specification) with printed hex value by manufacturer (trusted value). An IoT device encodes the binary as decminal - Golang returns the received value to Hex.

received decimal value is:

```
var V = 10736581604118680000
fmt.Sprintf("%016X", m.V)[2:14]) // adds uppercase and truncation of output
```

provides `000015877CD1`

The expected trusted output is `000015877CD0`

the engraved Hex on the key is `95 000015877CD0 01`

http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-hex.htm (trusted?) indicates that the golang function used has lost precision. binary values that encode to 19 decimal digits can be converted to Hex by Golang without loss of precision (using function above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
    "strconv"
)

func hexdec(s string) uint64 {
    d := uint64(0)
    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        x := uint64(s[i])
        if x >= 'a' {
            x -= 'a' - 'A'
        }
        d1 := x - '0'
        if d1 > 9 {
            d1 = 10 + d1 - ('A' - '0')
        }
        if 0 > d1 || d1 > 15 {
            panic("hexdec")
        }
        d = (16 * d) + d1
    }
    return d
}

func main() {
    x := "95000015877CD001"
    fmt.Println(x)
    n, err := strconv.ParseUint(x, 16, 64)
    fmt.Println(n, err)
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%016X", n)[2:14]
    fmt.Println(s)
    z, t := big.NewInt(0).SetString(x, 16)
    fmt.Println(z, t)
    s = fmt.Sprintf("%016X", z)[2:14]
    fmt.Println(s)
    fmt.Println(hexdec(x))
}
```

Output:

```
95000015877CD001
10736581604118679553 <nil>
000015877CD0
10736581604118679553 true
000015877CD0
10736581604118679553
```

Note that you are near the limits of 64-bit integers:

```
uint64  the set of all unsigned 64-bit integers (0 to 18446744073709551615)
```

Where does

```
Var V = 10736581604118680000
```

come from?

---

The number 10736581604118680000 is a floating-point approximation (1.073658160411868e+19) of the integer 10736581604118679553. The manufacturer probably doesn't understand floating-point: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). Given the integer 10736581604118680000, Go calculates the correct result. Go is mathematically correct.

So let's try telling Go that 10736581604118680000 is not an exact integer, that it's an approximate floating-point number.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    d := "10736581604118680000"
    f, err := strconv.ParseFloat(d, 64)
    fmt.Println(f, err)
    z := uint64(f)
    fmt.Println(z)
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%016X", z)[2:14]
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Output:

```
1.073658160411868e+19 <nil>
10736581604118679552
000015877CD0
```

While this trick works in this case, it's not guaranteed to work in all cases. The real solution is for the manufacturer to employ some competent mathematicians. I wonder what other bugs there are in their software and hardware.

Comment: The generation of the decimal representation is a remote hardware device and we cannot make assumptions about the function it uses to create it (in error or not). Subject to further research and testing we get what we get.

I need to understand how to get the correct precision when using GoLang compared to other reference tools that provide a different result

Comment: As you can easily see and prove for yourself, Go is correct.

Comment: They are likely using a 64-bit floating-point approximation: 1.073658160411868e+19. [IEEE floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

Comment: Agreed - the hardware is approximating 10736581604118679553 to 10736581604118680000, but all online DectoHex converters I've tried calculate this to 95000015877cd000 - curious to know why the GO function converts the given approximation to another value?

Comment: @user2314105: It's simple. Most people don't understand floating-point arithmetic. Go does. [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). See my revised answer.